# cakephp : Illegal mix of collations (tis620_thai_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Tags: sql, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2, cakephp

i got

```
 SQL Error: 1267: Illegal mix of collations (tis620_thai_ci,IMPLICIT) and    (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

when i insert non english to form

how to fix or hide  the problem
Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving the error because you have the collation in your Mysql set to latin1. You'll need to modify the collation of your tables (and possibly fields) to be tis620 and that should resolve the problem.